# How can I resolve the nested $q.all by order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, deferred

I have two promise function, `getToken()`, `getUser(token)` in my angularjs Project.

I can run two operations like this:

```
$q.all({token: getToken(), userId: getUserId()})
.then(function(resolutions){
  var token  = resolutions.token;
  var userId = resolutions.userId;
});
```

But my `getUserId()` method takes a token as parameter. So I need get token first then get the userId and return token and userId. How can I do this using `$q` ?

I used chaniing like this:

```
return getToken().then(function(token){
      return getUserId(token).then(function(userid){
            return {token: token, userid: userid};
      })
})
```

But did not work, userid comes null.

Comment: Use `promise chaining` instead of `$q.all`

Comment: then you don't need `$q.all`, simply chain them one inside the other

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal Can I return token and userid results using promise chaning? How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain promises like following

```
getToken()
.then(function(token){
     return getUser(token)
     .then(function(userId){
          return {token, userId};
      })
})
```

Comment: I don't think that's smart enough, can we make thing by order with a recursive function?

Comment: @WeijingJayLin - I think having a recursive function for 2 promises does not make sense provided the functions and response are different . Though, a better one liner can be `getToken().then((token) => getUser(token).then((userId) => ({token, userId})));`

Comment: yeah, you are right... it is not a supper long list